# What does apt need to be healed of a bad setup?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, packaging, aptitude, gpg

I made a couple of earlier posts regarding a libssl-dev that, it seemed, was not removable. Some of the replies touched on that there was a problem with apt, and now that someone posted the command to force uninstalling a package, I only have an issue with ack:

```
Setting up apt (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10) ...
gpg: gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=03)
Invalid option "--primary-keyring"
gpg: read_keyblock: read error: invalid packet
gpg: enum_keyblocks(read) failed: invalid keyring
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up apt (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10) ...
gpg: Invalid option "--primary-keyring"
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=03)
gpg: read_keyblock: read error: invalid packet
gpg: enum_keyblocks(read) failed: invalid keyring
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

I deleted /etc/apt/trusted.gpg. It didn't work. I copied a trusted.gpg from a machine where it was working as well. Still didn't work.

What can I do to satisfy apt configuration so I can get back to updating my software normally?